# Which processes swaps memory

Tags: linux, centos, memory, swap, top

I can see swap's total, used, free etc. sizes from `top` command.
But I can't figure out which process uses swap, is it possible to find out swap memory by process?

I'm running CentOS 6.3.

Comment: This has been answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479953/how-to-find-out-which-processes-are-swapping-in-linux

Comment: Somehow related: http://superuser.com/questions/300004/how-can-i-find-out-processes-are-using-swap-space?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

You could use **ps** and some quick **awk** maths to gain the answer.

The command that you can use is this...

```
$ ps -eo rss,vsz,pid,cmd | awk '{print $2-$1,$0}' | sort -nr | head
```

The first column out the output should be the swap usage.

**rss / resident set size**

resident set size, the non-swapped physical memory that a task has used (inkiloBytes).  (alias rssize, rsz).

**vsz / virtual memory size**

virtual memory size, the process in KiB (1024-byte units).  Device mappings are currently excluded; this is subject to change.

**Awk maths**

If rss (Column 1) is the non swapped memory and vsz(Column 2) is the physical memory, then..

```
swap = vsz - rss
```

Comment: No... the virtual memory size also considers the size of shared libraries, the executable itself, mapped memory areas (could be files mmap(2)-ed), ...